# How to fix "Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted"

Tags: next.js, app-router

I am using the App router in my Next.js project and I have a component named `search.tsx` which imports `useRouter` from `next/navigation.`

```js
'use client';

import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { MagnifyingGlassIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { createUrl } from 'lib/utils';

export default function Search() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchValue(searchParams?.get('q') ?? '');
  }, [searchParams, setSearchValue]);

  function onSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const val = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
    const search = val.search as HTMLInputElement;
    const newParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());

    if (search.value) {
      newParams.set('q', search.value);
    } else {
      newParams.delete('q');
    }

    router.push(createUrl('/search', newParams));
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="w-max-[550px] relative w-full lg:w-80 xl:w-full">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Search for products..."
        autoComplete="off"
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
        className="w-full rounded-lg border bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm text-black placeholder:text-neutral-500 dark:border-neutral-800 dark:bg-transparent dark:text-white dark:placeholder:text-neutral-400"
      />
      <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 mr-3 flex h-full items-center">
        <MagnifyingGlassIcon className="h-4" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This is how I am using the `useRouter` and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting this error

```
error Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted
    at Search (./components/layout/navbar/search.tsx:18:78)
```

I tried switching to `useRouter` from `next/router` but it didn't work.

Comment: Which version of Next?

Comment: Next.js v13.4.13-canary.15

Comment: Do you have a root `layout.tsx` file?

Comment: seems the issue is with the RootLayout.